# Parse XML File that is Dyanamically Generated

Tags: php, html, xml, download, simplexml

I am integrating the API from our monitoring software (PRTG) into our website and attempting to use a function that generates a list of data in XML format. As it is generated as needed, the URL doesn't point to an existing file.

I tried using "simplexml_load_file" and "simplexml_load_string" and passing the URL with no luck. I've also tried use "file_put_contents" to first save the file, but it also fails since the URL doesn't actually point to a file.

How can this be made to work?

```
<?php

$prtg_url = "http://prtg.domain.net:8080/";
$prtg_user = "username";
$prtg_hash = "passwordhash";

function getSensorData($deviceid)
{
    $sensor_xml_file = $GLOBALS['prtg_url'] . "api/table.xml?content=sensors&output=xml&columns=objid,type,device,sensor,status&id=" . $deviceid . "&username=" . $GLOBALS['prtg_user'] . "&passhash=" . $GLOBALS['prtg_hash'];
    file_put_contents("sensor.xml", fopen($sensor_xml_file, 'r'));

    $sensors = simplexml_load_file("sensor.xml");

    foreach ($sensors->item as $sensor)
    {
        $sensor_ping = $sensor->ping;
        $sensor_id = $sensor->objid;
        $sensor_type = $sensor->type;
        $sensor_typeraw = $sensor->type_raw;

        echo $sensor_ping . "</br>";
        echo $sensor_id . "</br>";
        echo $sensor_type . "</br>";
        echo $sensor_typeraw . "</br>";
    }
}

getSensorData("3401");

?>
```

Comment: Do you get any content from the location in the file load location? Do you allow open file to remote location in your php Settings?

Comment: simplexml_load_file normally works with an URL as well (if it wouldn't, fopen wouldn't as well).

Comment: allow_url_fopen is enabled and I am using PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be something to do with the file handler. You could try using simplexml_load_file() with your URL. For example:

```
$url = $GLOBALS['prtg_url']
       . "api/table.xml?content=sensors&output=xml&columns=objid,type,device,sensor,status&id=" 
       . $deviceid . "&username=" . $GLOBALS['prtg_user'] 
       . "&passhash=" . $GLOBALS['prtg_hash']);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Comment: If file_get_contents works with URL, simplexml_load_file does so as well. (edited)

Comment: Older versions of PHP require the URL to be raw encoded, prior to 5.1 though.

Comment: I have already tried this approach as well. When I visit the URL in my browser it just instantly opens an XML File Download.

Comment: What happens when you output the contents from file descriptor without the XML parsing?

Comment: I didn't quite understand that. Can you show an example or explain a bit more? I have echoed $sensor_xml_file and the URL it exports works fine when copy pasted. I tried a var_dump on ($sensors) which is the simplexml_load_file result and it loads for about 45 seconds then times out.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $sensor_xml_file);
$xmlString = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
$sensors = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'header'  => "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n",          
    'timeout' => 60
  )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$url = $GLOBALS['prtg_url']
   . "api/table.xml?content=sensors&output=xml&columns=objid,type,device,sensor,status&id=" 
   . $deviceid . "&username=" . $GLOBALS['prtg_user'] 
   . "&passhash=" . $GLOBALS['prtg_hash']);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $results;
```

This forces a 60 second timeout on the operation, that way you can see if it actually fetches any results. If it does return incomplete results, switch to using XMLReader for your parser.

Comment: I get failed to open stream when using this code as well as when using open() for XMLReader. It has to be the way the URL is formatted I think since the actual file is in the URL at "prtg.domain.com/api/table.xml" and the additional params are just to specify what data it formats.

Comment: I found that I can change "table.xml" to "table.json" and it outputs the contents to the browser rather than a file download, but I am still running into the same issue when trying to read the contents via PHP.

Comment: Hmm, Sounds like you can't open the location with the way URL is provided. Try rawurlencode($url), your browser does the equivalent. Also what headers does the endpoint sends out?

Comment: It errors with "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" when using rawurlencode on the $url before passing it to file_get_contents

Comment: The encoded URL is reported as http%3A%2F%2Fprtg.mydomain.net%3A8080%2Fapi%2Ftable.json%3Fcontent%3Dsensors%26output%3Dxml%26columns%3Dobjid%2Ctype%2Cdevice%2Csensor%2Cstatus%26id%3D3401%26username%3Dmyuser%26passhash%mypasshash